# Substitute for Cross-domain request with JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, .htaccess, cgi

I have a JavaScript on a server named `kopernikus.science.net` that wants to access a file on a different server named `galileo.science.net`. Here a toy example of what I have in mind:

```
code residing on  http://kopernikus.science.net/makecalendar.js :

    var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
    request.open("GET","galileo.science.net/calendar", false);
    request.send(null);
    document.getElementById("calendar").innerHTML =
        "<div>" + request.responseText.split('\n')[0] + "</div>";
```

Unfortunately, due to the "same origin policy" of modern web browsers, the script is forbidden from accessing the data on a different domain.

Of course, my question is:

> How can I access the remote file anyway?
>
> Solutions outside JavaScript are allowed, like mirroring the file in question or tweaking `.htaccess`. What are my options? Which require the least amount of permissions on the web server?

The file in question is a calendar in vcalendar format which changes regularly. I'm on a shared host and don't have sysadmin rights, but I can run PHP and CGI scripts and can change some parts of the `.htaccess` file.

Comment: If the domain names you show are the real ones, you should be able to use `document.domain`: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Some options:

1. If you're in control of the servers and your users will be using an up-to-date web browser, you can use [CORS](http://www.w3.org/TR/access-control/). Sadly, there is no CORS support in IE7 or below. In IE8, it's there, but you have to use an [`XDomainRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) instead of an `XMLHttpRequest` (other browsers, like Chrome and Firefox, handle CORS completely transparently with `XMLHttpRequest`).
2. If not, you can use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP), which works with all browsers.
3. You can use [`document.domain`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/origin-0.html#dom-document-domain) to specify that both of those pages (if they're really subdomains of the same `science.net` domain) are in the same origin. That works well across browsers, but it has the disadvantage that you first have to load the target document into a window (probably a hidden iframe) before you can access it, because the target document *also* has to set `document.domain` (to show that it wants to cooperate with you).
4. Another alternative, for public stuff, is [using YQL as a proxy](http://ajaxian.com/archives/using-yql-as-a-proxy-for-cross-domain-ajax).
5. If all of those fail, your only real option is to have a proxy script on your server that you query, which then uses *server-side* code to query the resource from the other domain (since this restriction only applies client-side).

Those are listed in roughly the order in which I would use them. E.g., use CORS if you control the servers and know your clients will be using up to date browsers; if not, look at JSONP (although from your comment below, you probably can't); if not either of those, perhaps `document.domain` is the answer; etc., etc., working down the list to the option of last resort (proxying).

Comment: Does JSONP require that the file `galileo.science.net/calendar` is in JSON format? Unfortunately, it is not, and I don't have control over that.

Comment: @Heinrich: Yes. With JSONP, what you're requesting is basically a script file, and it does have to be set up in a specific way. If you don't have control over the thing you're requesting, you'll be looking at option #1 (`document.domain`, if they're really subdomains of the same domain), #2 (CORS, if the server allows any origin), option 4, or the freshly-added option 5.

Comment: Can you give an example of how to use `document.domain`? Simply by adding `document.domain = "science.net"` in the JavaScript?

Comment: @Heinrich: Yup, it's that simple. More (a little, anyway) on the MDC page: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/document.domain Note that it has to be done on *both* pages, indicating their intent to cooperate. This requires that you load the HTML you're planning to connect with into an iframe or something, rather than via XHR.

Comment: I have to admit I'd forgotten that *both sides* have to do the `document.domain` thing. I've downgraded it in the list. :-)

Comment: Ah, the problem is that it's not HTML that I am connecting to. The document is in vCalendar format as mentioned. Basically, I can't do anything on the server where the file is located. (Otherwise, I would just export it as JSON, obviously). Could you give examples of method No. 5? Ideally, I'd like to tweak `.htaccess` a bit, or write a tiny php script.

Comment: @Heinrich: It's not going to be an `.htaccess` tweak, but it's dead easy in PHP thanks to the cURL support built into the platform: http://www.php.net/manual/en/curl.examples-basic.php Just create a page on your server that, in turn, goes off and grabs the data, then hands it back to you. You'll probably want to protect that page in some way so others can't abuse it, but that should get you started.

Answer (score 1):

> Unfortunately, due to the "same origin
>   policy" of modern web browsers, the
>   script is forbidden from accessing the
>   data on a different domain.

But what you could do is use [json-p](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.getJSON/).

> Script and JSONP requests are not
>   subject to the same origin policy
>   restrictions.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <style>img{ height: 100px; float: left; }</style>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.4.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="images">

</div>
<script>
$.getJSON("http://api.flickr.com/services/feeds/photos_public.gne?jsoncallback=?",
  {
    tags: "cat",
    tagmode: "any",
    format: "json"
  },
  function(data) {
    $.each(data.items, function(i,item){
      $("<img/>").attr("src", item.media.m).appendTo("#images");
      if ( i == 3 ) return false;
    });
  });</script>

</body>
</html>
```

As a side note the modern browser support [CORS](http://www.nczonline.net/blog/2010/05/25/cross-domain-ajax-with-cross-origin-resource-sharing/)(Internet Explorer 8+, Firefox 3.5+, Safari 4+, and Chrome).

Comment: Unfortunately, the file I'm accessing is not in JSON format. I don't have control over it.

Comment: Then json-p is won't work(but you could proxy it yourself?). Or you could also use YQL to crossdomain requests => http://developer.yahoo.com/yql/. YQL will do the proxing for you.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you can deploy PHP on kopernikus.science.net, why not just proxy it there...

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript');
print file_get_contents('http://galileo.science.net/calendar');
```

(and of course you could potentially cache it briefly on the proxy and client to cut down on network noise)

**Update**

If you want to cache....

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: application/x-javascript');
define("CACHEDIR", '/tmp/webcache/');
$cache_time=14 * 24 * 60 * 60; // cache for 2 weeks
$key=sha1('http://galileo.science.net/calendar');

if (@filemtime(CACHEDIR . $key) > time() - $cache_time) { // cache good
    print file_get_contents(CACHEDIR . $key);
} else {  // cache stale
    $freshcopy=file_get_contents('http://galileo.science.net/calendar');
    print $freshcopy;
    if (!file_put_contents(CACHEDIR . $key, $freshcopy)) {
       // report a problem writing files
    }
}
```

Comment: This looks like a solution. Could you elaborate a bit on a caching mechanism, assuming that it doesn't take more than a few lines of PHP code?

Answer (score 0):

Use [JSONP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSONP#JSONP). In the javascript, embed a new script element in the page that has the interface of the other server as source.

The server should return something like this:

```
callCallback({"some":"JSONString"});
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very known problem and JSONP is solution of the problem. You can google and fine a tons of information on that. You might consider this as example of usage JSONP with and without jQuery.

http://www.beletsky.net/2010/07/json-jsonp-and-same-origin-policy-issue.html

Comment: I have no control over the format of the file on `galileo.science.net`.